# NodeJS: Getting the values from the result of a multiple statement MySQL query

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am getting data from a database using a multiple statement query in Node.js.

The result of my query is of the following form:

```
  [ [ RowDataPacket {
      name: 'Jericho',
      country: 'Canada',
      sex: 'Male',
      age: 12 } ],
  [ RowDataPacket {
      interpretation: 'a complex situation' } ],
  [ RowDataPacket {
      team: 'The Horses',
      colour: 'Purple' } ],
  [ RowDataPacket {
      start_day: 'Monday',
      end_day: 'Friday' } ] ]
```

I am trying to get the `start_day` and `end_day` values from the fourth `RowDataPacket` so that I can join them with a dash (e.g. Monday-Friday). 
I have the following code:

```
var days = rows[3]; //rows is the result of the query
console.log(days.start_day);
console.log(days.end_day);
```

However the result of console.log() is the following:

```
undefined
undefined
```

I am not sure why the `start_day` and `end_day` values are being printed as `undefined`. Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: You have an Array inside an Array as result of your query, therefore you have to `var days = rows[0][3]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RowDataPacket is the constructor function that creates an object, looks like `this new RowDataPacket(start_day, end_day)`

You can access that using [0], 0th index

```
var days = rows[3];
console.log(days[0].start_day);
console.log(days[0].end_day);
```